# Revulytics data not showing in Dashboard

Tags: sdk

I am using Revulytics SDK to track feature usage and came across the below problem.

I am sending feature usage after properly setting up the SDK configuration etc, using the EventTrack() method like this:

```
GenericReturn grTest = telemetryObj.EventTrack("FeatureUsage", textBoxName.Text.ToString(), null, false);
```

This returns OK and usually, I can see the usage data in the dashboard. However, after multiple tests, the data I am sending does not show up on the dashboard.

Can anyone hint me how to debug this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue when first working with this SDK. 
I was able to address this as soon as I understood the following:

1. There are event quotas for the incoming events;
2. Event names are used for making the distinction.

So when I was sending dummy test data, it made it there, but when I sent some demo data for stakeholders, it was not showing up.

I think the same happens here. You're getting the event name form textbox.text... Pretty sure that varies every time you run the code.

Here are the things to keep in mind when testing your code:

- the server has a mechanism to discard / consider events;
- implicitly, it allows first xx events depending on the quota;
- if you are sending more than xx events, they will not show up in reports.

So, you must control which events to discard and which to consider (there are a couple of levels you can configure, and based of them you can get the events in various types of reports).
Find the "Tracked Events Whitelist Management". You will be able to control these things form there.
This blog helped me (it is not SDK documentation): https://www.revulytics.com/blog/getting-started-with-usage-intelligence-part2-event-tracking

Good luck!